# Loop through array of unknown size C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, sizeof, function-definition

I am trying to traverse a `double` array of an unknown size.

Why does the following not work?

```
for (unsigned int = 1; i < sizeof(anArray)/sizeof(double); i++) {
    ...
}
```

Everything compiles fine (`g++ -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 app.cpp -o app`), but the program simply does not even enter the loop.

Full function:

```
struct stock_data {
   int sell_index;
   int buy_index;
   double profit;
};

stock_data max_profit(double price_array[]) {
   int sell_index = -1, buy_index = -1, 
      min = 0;

   double profit = 0.0;

   for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {

      if(price_array[i] - price_array[min] > profit) {
         sell_index = min;
         buy_index = i;
         profit = price_array[i] - price_array[min];
      }

      if(price_array[i] < price_array[min]) {
        min = i;
      }
   }  

   return {sell_index, buy_index, profit};
}

int main() {
   double yesterday[] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
   stock_data data = max_profit(yesterday);
   cout << data.profit << endl;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(anArray)` is telling you the size of a pointer, which when divided by the size of a double, is 0 or 1.

Comment: My crystal ball says you passed `anArray` into this function and it decayed to a pointer.  Wish I could see enough code to be sure.

Comment: where this array is declared? if it's in some other block it may not work.

Comment: Not enough code to determine anything.  That code would work if you declared anArray as double anArray[<something>] and anArray hasn't decayed to just a pointer.

Comment: Talk is cheap. Show us the code.

Comment: it must of decayed to a pointer.

Comment: You mean "must have", "must of" is just nonsense. In your loop, are you sure you want to initialize `i` (which is missing) to `1`, and not `0`? As written, even if you'd managed to get the number of elements correct, you'd skip the first element in the array (assuming you index using `i` and not `i-1` or something similar).

Comment: `unsigned int = 1;` should give a compilation error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++ operator sizeof is a compile-time operator. That is its value is calculated by the compiler not at run-time.

So if as you say the array has unknown size then the compiler can not calculate the size of the memory occupied by the array.

So it is evident that anArray is pointer to first element of the array that you might pass to the function.

Thus this expression

```
sizeof(anArray)/sizeof(double)
```

is equivalent to expression

```
sizeof( double * )/sizeof( double ).
```

You have to pass also the size of the array explicitly to the function.

Take into account that an array passed by value to a function is converted to  pointer to its first element.

Or the other approach is to use  conteiner `std::vector<double>`instead of the arrays.

You could declare your function like

```
stock_data max_profit(double price_array[], size_t size );
```

and call it like

```
 stock_data data = max_profit( yesterday, 
                               sizeof( yesterday ) / sizeof( *yesterday ) );
```

Comment: Or use `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: @Cole Johnson Initially he wrote in his post that he deals with arrays of unknown sizes. So I did not suggest to use std::array because  its size also shall be known at compile time.

Comment: `std::vector` OTOH, is dynamic and does not need a size specified at compile time

Comment: @Cole Johnson I said about std::array.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof(anArray)` returns the size of the type `anArray`, probably `*double`. You have to pass the array size as an additional parameter or use `std::vector` and it's `size` method.

Have a look at the C main function `main(argc, argv)` where `argv` are the parameters of the program and `argc` is their count. Or take strings, their end is determined by a special character \0 that determines its end. But that's error prone.

In C/C++ there is no other way with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `max_profit` does not know the size of the array `price_array`.
If you want the function to accept arrays of varying size, you have two options:

- Pass the `size` value alongside the array (C style)
- Use `std::vector` object which holds the `size` inside (C++ style)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to avoid passing the size, you can add a NaN at the end of the array and check for it in the loop.

```
#include<cmath>
...
for(int i = 0; !isnan(price_array[i]; i++){
    ...
}
```

To add the NaN when you're declaring the array:

```
double price_array{0.0d, 5.9d, nan()};
```

Of course, this assumes you won't have any other NaNs in your array as part of the actual data.